# Import CSV data faster in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building an import module to import a large set of orders from a csv file. I have a model called Order where the data needs to be stored.

A simplified version of the Order model is below

```
sku
quantity
value
customer_email
order_date
status
```

When importing the data two things have to happen

1. Any dates or currencies need to be cleaned up i.e. dates are represented as strings in the csv, this needs to be converted into a Rails Date object and currencies need to converted to a decimal by removing any commas or dollar signs
2. If a row already exists it has to be updated, the uniqueness is checked based on two columns.

Currently I use a simple csv import code

```
CSV.foreach("orders.csv") do |row|
  order = Order.first_or_initialize(sku: row[0], customer_email: row[3])
  order.quantity = row[1]
  order.value= parse_currency(row[2])
  order.order_date = parse_date(row[4])
  order.status = row[5]
  order.save!
end
```

Where parse_currency and parse_date are two functions used to extract the values from strings. In the case of the date it is just a wrapper for Date.strptime.

I can add a check to see if the record already exists and do nothing in case it already exists and that should save a little time. But I am looking for something that is significantly faster. Currently importing around 100k rows takes around 30 mins with an empty database. It will get slower as the data size increases.

So I am basically looking for a faster way to import the data.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**

After some more testing based on the comments here I have an observation and a question. I am not sure if they should go here or if I need to open a new thread for the questions. So please let me know if I have to move this to a separate question.

I ran a test using Postgres copy to import the data from the file and it took less than a minute. I just imported the data into a new table without any validations. So the import can be much faster.

The Rails overhead seems to be coming from 2 places

1. The multiple database calls that are happening i.e. the first_or_initialize for each row. This ends up becoming multiple SQL calls because it has to first find the record and then update it and then save it.
2. Bandwidth. Each time the SQL server is called the data flows back and forth which adds up to a lot of time

Now for my question. How do I move the update/create logic to the database i.e. If an order already exists based on the sku and customer_email it needs to update the record else a new record needs to be created. Currently with rails I am using the first_or_initialize method to get the record in case it exists and update it, else I am creating a new one and saving it. How do I do that in SQL.

I could run a raw SQL query using ActiveRecord connection execute but I do not think that would be a very elegant way of doing it. Is there a better way of doing that?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. There used to be a gem called `FasterCSV` - not sure if it's still current.... might be worth looking into. That said - google for "rails csv gem fast" or something to see if there are others...

Comment: Thanks for that. I did run across faster_csv in my search but it has not been updated in a few years so I did not really spend a lot of time on it. I looked at smarter_csv and it looks like a possible option, it allows you to process the csv in chunks. But I could not really figure out how to run the first_or_initialize on those chunks, since I would have to run them on each item that is returned by smarter_csv. Based on my research I think the way to go would be database transactions, but I am not sure how to do that in rails and make it behave like first_or_initialize.

Comment: hmmm, you should be able to use `first_or_initialize` on any row returned... a chunk is just an array of rows isn't it?

Comment: Note: I've often found when actually profiling this sort of thing, that the ruby-code can be the bottleneck - especially when parsing strings into other formats... might be worth checking if that's your issue, and then figuring out if thee's anything you can do on that end of things. Cos if it's your ruby, then it won't matter what library you use for the CSV-part ;)

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer. If I were to use chunks it would be the same as my current code, I would have to run it for each row so the speed would be similar. One way I thought of speeding that up would be to put the chunks into separate background processes and import it. But then that might be over complicating the situation and I am not sure how conflicts would behave. So before I go down that road I am trying to see if there is a simpler way.

Comment: Consider bypassing ActiveRecord entirely. Do whatever processing you need to do to the CSV in plain Ruby, and then send the CSV directly to the database. MySQL and Postgres both have mechanisms for importing CSV and they are incredibly fast.

Comment: Yes do what Matt said if you don't have any callbacks and validations (Ruby object instantiation takes significant time) and use uniqueness constraints on database as a check.

Comment: Yeah, I've done that (bypassing AR) before - you can map a chunk-worth of data into a multiple insert statement and that can considerably speed things up.

Comment: Thanks everyone, based on the feedback I did some additional testing and updated the question.

Answer (score 3):

Since ruby 1.9 fastcsv is now part of ruby core. You don't need to use a special gem. Simply use `CSV`.

With 100k records ruby takes 0.018 secs / record. In my opinion most of your time will be used within `Order.first_or_initialize`. This part of your code takes an extra roundtrip to your database. Initialization of an `ActiveRecord` takes it time too. But to realy be sure I would suggest that you benchmark your code.

```
Benchmark.bm do |x|
   x.report("CSV evel") { CSV.foreach("orders.csv") {} }
   x.report("Init: ") { 1.upto(100_000) {Order.first_or_initialize(sku:  rand(...), customer_email: rand(...))} } # use rand query to prevent query caching 
   x.report('parse_currency') { 1.upto(100_000) { parse_currency(...} }
   x.report('parse_date') { 1.upto(100_000) { parse_date(...} }
end
```

You should also watch memory consumption during your import. Maybe the garbage collection does not run often enough or objects are not cleaned up.

To gain speed you can follow *Matt Brictson* hint and bypass `ActiveRecord`.
You can try the gem `activerecord-import` or you can start to go parallel, for instance multiprocessing with `fork` or multithreading with `Thread.new`.

Comment: +1 for using activerecord-import for batch importing large sets of data. It will greatly speed up your import by avoiding round-trips to the database for each record.

Comment: Thanks for that. Based on what you said I am doing some testing to figure out where the problems lie and realized that I am having additional speed issues when I push it to heroku because it is running out of memory with larger files after it gets past 10K rows or so. So I was wondering if there was some way to manually call garbage collection?

Comment: You can call `GC.start`. This call is expensive, so performance can drop further more. Some times ciruclar references can lead to memory leaks. In such cases Ruby can't recognize that an object is no longer needed. Some times it helps for instance to set variables explicit to nil like `order = nil; row = nil` at the end of a loop.